# iOS; Push notification is not work when the app is not running or in background

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem with detecting a push notification from APNS.

If there is a push notification from APNS when the app is not running or in background,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

is not work.

And when I'm back to the foreground without selecting a push notification message from notification centre, it is not work.

How can I solve this problem?

I'm testing the app in iOS 6.13 and iOS 7.0.4.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: It seem that you have not read document care fully. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4

Comment: Read for application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: First ensure the basic setup of the APNS ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple documentation:

> Implement this method if your app supports the remote-notification background mode.

Which mean the method you are using focuses on the background task. And only available after iOS 7.0.

I recommend you use `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`.

From Apple documentation:

> If the app is running and receives a remote notification, the app calls this method to process the notification.

Comment: Do you get this working when App is not running. ? I mean how to handle the Push notifications when the App is in not running state ? What if, if you receive many notifications & you did not open the app, neither did you tap the system's notification panel. How are you preserving those push for a later retrieval.

Comment: @BalramTiwari, If a notification for an application arrives when that application is not running, the device alerts the user that the application has data waiting for it. If the user does not tap the notification panel, you get nothing

Answer (score 2):

Actually,the first receiver of notifications is system,not your app.

If your app isn't in foreground, app's `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` will never be called until you tap the notification to make your app becomes to the foreground again.

When a push notification arrives and the user clicks '`cancel`', `your app has no way to read that push notification again`. You have to implement a separate functionality (most probably on `server-side`) to fetch a list of notifications sent to this device.

Comment: What if system doesn't alert me about my app's notification when in background? Although `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is being called in foreground.